# Oh-my-zsh mac os X broken

Tags: macos, oh-my-zsh

This morning an Oh-my-zsh update.
Since then, each time I launch my terminal :

```
grep: unrecognized option `--exclude-dir=.cvs'
```

Idem when I try to use git-flow

any idea ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Grep versions lower than 2.5.3 do not have this option. Try to upgrade your grep, or comment out the lines

```
for PATTERN in .cvs .git .hg .svn; do
GREP_OPTIONS+="--exclude-dir=$PATTERN "
done
```

at .oh-my-zsh/lib/grep.zsh line 9. Then it works fine again.

Comment: I ended up updating my OS to Maverick. updating by the same way my grep...
I guess it should be reported as a backward compatibility issue for zsh.
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Thanks!...for older grep you can use `--exclude` flag.